# Fetching the last 10 sold items using Shopify Liquid template

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am working on a Shopify store and I want to display the last 10 sold items using Liquid templates. How can I achieve this within Shopify's Liquid templating system? Are there any built-in tags or filters that can help me fetch and display this information? Any guidance or example code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way by far to do that is to install a custom App in your store that has two things it does. One, it summarizes your recent orders and figures out the 10 most recent things you sold. Two, it has a proxy that makes those items available (as Liquid or JSON, your choice). Then, in your theme, where you want to show those items, you just make a call to the Proxy, and boom, the results are available for display in your store. You can even use a theme app extension to make it drag/drop in your theme customizer.